# How to configure javamelody for grails 2.4.4? Getting "Bad artifact coordinates"!

Tags: grails, java-melody

As per grails javamelody plugin, I have added dependency of
"compile ':grails-melody:1.54.0'"

But I get the error:
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates :grails-melody:1.54.0, expected format is < groupId>:< artifactId>[:< extension>[:< classifier>]]:< version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

I also tried "compile 'grails-melody:grails-melody:1.54.0'" but got the error:
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact grails-melody:grails-melody:jar:1.54.0

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: have you added it to the `dependencies{}` instead of the `plugins{}`?

Comment: @cfrick that did the trick. Tx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must add it to the `plugins{}` block (and not to `dependencies{}`)

Comment: You comment helped me realize I had the opposite issue. I was able to get my maven dependency working by moving it from the plugins block to the dependencies block, Thanks!