# Grails Download zip file as dependency

Tags: maven, grails

I have a standalone custom code packed as a zip file(custom-1.0.zip) using maven-shade-plugin –uploaded to my company's artifactory

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com/mypackage/domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

I want to use this zip file in my Grails 2.3.5 project which is configured to use maven for resolving  dependencies. I believe I need to do following:

1. Download the zip file from artifactory to local maven repository
2. Copy the zip file from local maven repository to web-app/resources folder of my project

I added following to Build.groovy to download the zip file:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

dependencies {
     compile ("com.mypackage.domain:custom:1.0")
}
```

…
..

```
plugins {
     compile ("com.mypackage.domain:custom:1.0")

}
```

Above code downloads the jar, pom and zip file to my local maven repository and then fails

```
Loading Grails 2.3.5
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: com.mypackage.domain/custom/1.0/custom-1.0.pom
|Downloading: com.mypackage.domain/custom/1.0/custom-1.0.zip
|Downloading: com.mypackage.domain/custom/1.0/custom-1.0.jar
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
Error |
Zip C:\Users\userid\.m2\repository\com\mypackage\domain\custom\1.0\custom-
1.0.zip is not a valid plugin
```

Does anyone has a working example for downloading zip using Grails 2.3.5 and copying to desired folder?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the following unless the `custom` artifact is built as a plugin. You can remove

```
plugins {
     compile ("com.mypackage.domain:custom:1.0")
}
```

and edit the dependencies to include the type:

```
dependencies {
     compile ("com.mypackage.domain:custom:1.0:zip")
}
```

then compile your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Removing plugin is fine but adding  colon - ':' before path does not fix this.

Comment: @RohitKumar Grails 2.x version onwards, you should have ":" in front of the dependency.

Comment: Adding  ":" fails the process-                                                                            |Loading Grails 2.3.5
    Error |
    There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates 
    :com.mypackage.domain:custom:1.0, expected format is <groupId>:
    <artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to 
  see the full trace

Comment: @RohitKumar ya seems like https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065980/1746118 answers why. Edited tthe answer.

Comment: No above post does not answer my question. It says add dependency to plugin. That's where I posted this question. I need an working example where a zip file is downloaded to specified folder in Grails-2.3.5

Comment: @RohitKumar Did you try the edited answer? All you need to do is get rid of the plugin section in your code and make sure the dependency details other than that are correct.